# how to calculate disk usage on a kubernetes node?

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have a service on my kubernetes cluster that generates massive assets to my machine's hard disk. Some of that information could also be served statically by a different service in my system. The save location is mapped to an actual folder on my disk.

I already found that I can see some information about my "ephemral" storage capacity and allocatbility through `kubectl describe node` but the data doesn't align with what I see when I run `df -h` on my machine's terminal. on the node, I can see that I could allocate 147GB and on my terminal I can see that I could only allocate 98GB (this means we probably have some reserved space by Kubernetes in our deployments). I would like my metrics to reflect the actual state of the hard drive.

My Question:
How do I check through Kubernetes's python package what's the status of the storage on my machine ***without mounting my root path into the relevant container***? Is there an API to the metrics service that shows me the status of my machine's actual storage? I tried looking at the [Python API](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/README.md) and couldn't find it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes does not track overall storage available. It only knows things about emptyDir volumes and the filesystem backing those. If you're using a hostPath mount (which it sounds like you are), that is outside of Kube's view of the world. You can use something like node_exporter to gather those statistics yourself.